# Appium - Why is using a longPress touch action automatically clicking a button?

Tags: java, automated-tests, appium

I have created a mobile app with a form in it (appium 1.6, java-client 5.0.0 beta3, and android 5.1).

After several input fields, there is a submit button and a reset button. Since I have found that the mobile keyboard will cover up the other fields and causes the `findElement` function to not be able to find elements, I have done the following:

```
driver.hideKeyboard();
TouchAction touch = new TouchAction();
// using a long press action to scroll down to somewhere before the button
// another long press action press one input field
```

The `longPress` action does not at all touch the button. However, it automatically submits the form. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0):

TouchActions does not noticeably click the button.

What it does is, it sends the device the same request as a button would do after physically clicking the button.

If you would like to see the button being pressed, I suggest you use this code instead:

WebElement elementToClick = Driver.findElementBy(By.xpath("elementXPath"));
elementToClick.click();

Comment: I know that. However, in my case, the button is automatically clicked after the two long press action. My question is to find the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void longClick( String element ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebElement webElement = appiumDriver.findElement(By.xpath(element));

        TouchAction Action = new TouchAction(appiumDriver);
        Action.longPress(webElement).release().perform();
    }
```

Use this function, element is the xpath.